# creating excel template for vb.net export

Tags: vb.net, excel

Is there any way that I could create a template in excel for exporting data in vb.net?

I already created a code that will export data to excel from vb.net and create an excel design to display the data..However, when it comes to execution and exporting of data, the system is taking too long to process the command and ultimately won't respond and hangup.

Any idea if maybe there is a way that I could just create a template so the system only needs to send in the data to the template?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this (I made template file with office 2003):

= Create xls file that you will use as a template master, i.e: **Template.xls**

= Copy the file to any .xls name each time you do export, i.e: **data1.xls**

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile("Template.xls", "data1.xls", _
FileIO.UIOption.AllDialogs, FileIO.UICancelOption.DoNothing)
```

= Then you will use data1.xls as working database

Dont forget ..

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
```

So the code ...

```
Dim cnXLS As Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
Dim cmdXLS As Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter

cnXLS = New OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
        "data source= data1.xls ;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")
cmdXLS = New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", cnXLS)

'Codes as you need here
```

Hope this help you !

Comment: @mrkdenz .. this is just how to start, I'm sure uncle Google can help you .. : )